# How can I replace existing Activex controls?

Tags: html, vb6, vbscript, activex, ocx

I am sorry for not giving enough information earlier,I will mention a few things as to what the controls are doing first. These controls are ActiveX Controls/Modules written in Vb6.0, and they implement in supporting interface for data transmission between a training application(run on a learners machine), the Learning Management Server (LMS), and the Local data store. I have to download data from the local storage and these controls helps in doing just that, let me also tell you that the data that is being downloaded is related to the properties of the learner such as displaying FullName and Last name,options to either Proceed with the course last started or Refresh the course completely to start from begining. The ActiveX Controls are no longer supported in latest browsers and I have been assigned the task of removing these controls. I need any help regarding any technology that can help me achieve this. Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: We have absolutely **no idea** what your ActiveX controls do, and cannot assist without having a single clue as to what you are trying to accomplish.  Be much more specific about what you are trying to do, and try again.  Read the FAQ:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: If it's just forms and launching pages, isn't it obvious how that can be done in HTML?  It sounds like any old website which you've always been able to make in HTML.

Comment: @Brad and AshleyBrain- All I know is that there are these 3 controls that get downloaded from the Server, These help in validating the learners credentials and displaying course related content. The problem I am facing is that, all these dll's were developed using vb6.0, It works in IE6 and IE7, these dll's once downloaded get registered and the content launches in a new window. Current browsers like Chrome, Firefox and latest IE do not support.

Comment: @hrg, ... then you do not know enough to do this project.  You haven't explained at all what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Brad- I have very little information and very little knowledge about what these existing controls do :( I only have the dll's with me and No Code, I have provided you the information I could research on. All I know is that I am asked to replace them as a part of a task. Thanks for your time

Comment: Sounds like you need to explain to your boss that you have not been given enough info to do what has been asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in medieval times, Microsoft tried to own the internet by using a strategy called 'Embrace, Extend and Extinguish'. Fortunately, the US Justice department eventually busted them for it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend_and_extinguish

You've unfortunately inherited one of the 'extend' parts of this strategy.

Essentially, Microsoft made IE different to every other browser by making it run special ActiveX controls.

There really isn't a way to make a modern browser deal with this. You can ask your users to install IETab and try to run pages in compatibility mode, but essentially the best long term strategy is to toss these controls in the bin, grab the source code and re-write them in a modern language, like ASP.NET